# Passing a Variable into a String which is being pushed into an existing Array

Tags: javascript, django, arrays

I am attempting to pass a variable into a string while the string itself is being pushed into an *existing* array like so:

```
var myVar = 'slug';

myArray.push(['item one', '/path/to/' + myVar + '/']);
```

This is not working at all.  I can see the proper value get assigned to `myVar`; however, the `myVar` in the array is not even recognized as a variable.

This seems easy enough, but I'm obviously missing something.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:  Not a Javascript problem after all.**

As Alex demonstrated, this definitely *normally* works.  (And yes, this is an existing array.)

However, I neglected to mention that the push method is wrapped in bit of Django templating logic to have it only run on my dev instance, like thus:

```
{% ifequal INSTANCE 'DEVELOPMENT' %]
myArray.push(['item one', '/path/to/' + myVar + '/']);
{% endifequal %}
```

I didn't mention the logic because I didn't see how it could be interfering.  I had confirmed that:

1. everything with the logic was behaving as expected
2. the INSTANCE did in fact equal 'DEVELOPMENT'
3. and that line of Javascript was visible in the source, which wouldn't be the case if the logic was misbehaving.

However, if I remove that Django logic, everything with the Javascript works as desired.

For some reason, this server-side logic is preventing me from passing *any* external values into the array, client- or server-side.

As an experiment, I tried this...

```
myArray.push(['item one', '/path/to/{{ block slug }}undefined{{ endblock }}/']);
```

...with the following in a child template.

```
{{ block slug }}slug{{ endblock }}
```

The same thing happens.  With the template logic in place, the value is `/path/to/undefined`.  Without it, the value is `/path/to/slug` as desired.

Why this is happening is a mystery to me.  I can work around it, but if anyone has any thoughts, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks again.

---

*Noob side question: what's SO etiquette about altering post titles?*

Comment: *the myVar in the array is not even recognized as a variable* how did you decide this? Can we see the output of `console.log()`?

Comment: Anybody want to guess why this is tagged as "python"???

Answer (score 3):

[It definitely works](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/hPJZB/).

Perhaps you meant to concatenate the `Array` instead, with `concat()`? At the moment you are pushing a new `Array` onto the existing `Array` as a member, resulting in a multi dimensional `Array`.

I also assumed `myArray` already pointed to an `Array`. If not, just do `var myArray = []`.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  You're correct.  It definitely works.  I've traced the issue back to some Django template logic that I mistakenly assumed was innocent.  See my edits.

Comment: @polymorph I'm sorry, I don't know much about Django.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the array before using the push method:

```
var myVar = 'slug';
var myArray=new Array();
myArray.push(['item one', '/path/to/' + myVar + '/']);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is not working?

You are creating an array within an array.

You need to access the new arrays elements like this:

```
myArray[0][1] // this is "/paht/to/slug/
```

Re-reading your comments it sounds like you are trying to access a property of the array:

```
myArray.myVar
```

In javascript if you want to have a named element you need to use an object.

```
myObject = {};
myObject.myVar = "/path/to/slug/";
alert(myObject.myVar) // "/path/to/slug/"
```

Or you can add it directly to the array as a property:

```
myArray.myVar = "/path/to/slug/";
alert(myArray.myVar);
```